# How to show group of checkbox in CRUD layout in play 1.2.4 instade of multiselect?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I used OneToMany relation in my model class `@OneToMany
    public List<Skill> skills;`, It shows multiselection list in CRUD layout. Instead of this i want to show group of checkboxes in layout. Is this possible? And if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

By default CRUD tag *relationField* creates *select* with multiple="yes".
You can look into relationField.html view of the CRUD module to see how it is done.

You might get an idea that changing relationField tag may solve your problem. Then I suggest you check this discussion [How do I override CRUD tags in Play! Framework 1.2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936439/how-do-i-override-crud-tags-in-play-framework-1-2-4).